# Passport does not call the authentication strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

today I was trying to get a passport authentication working. The email and password is static now but I will change that later. I have a lot of debug messages but only the ones outside of the Strategy. No errors or warnings regarding passport are displayed.

I have already tried to use different body parser modes (extented = true, extented = false).

Strategy

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((email, password, done) => {
        console.log('Authentication started');
        var user = null;
        if(email == 'test@mytest.com') {
            if(password == 'test') {
                user = {
                    email
                }
                console.log('Authenticated')
                return done(null, user);
            }
        }
        console.log('Error')
        return done(null, user, {message: 'EMail or Password was wrong'});
    })
  );
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(err, user);
  });
};
```

app.js (contains only important parts)

```
const express = require('express');
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'secret' }));

// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Passport
const passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.get('/applications', (req,res) => {
    res.render('applications', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
app.post('/applications', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/applications',
      failureRedirect: '/',
      failureFlash: false
    })(req, res, next);
  });

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(7443, () => {
        console.log('HTTPS Server started on Port 7443')
});
http.createServer(app)
    .listen(7080, () => {
        console.log('HTTP Server started on Port 7080')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you are using the proper fields in your POST request.** I noticed that in your strategy, you use the variables `email` and `password`. While your variable names aren't important, the fields you send in your POST request are. By default, passport-local uses the POST fields `username` and `password`. If one of these fields aren't present, the authentication will fail. You can change this to use `email` instead like so:

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, (email, password, done) => {
      console.log('Authentication started');
      // Your authentication strategy
  })
);
```

Assuming you have the right POST fields, in order to use `req.user` in requests, you must have properly set up your `passport.deserializeUser` function. Testing your code, the authentication strategy is working fine for me, however I receive a reference error upon `deserializeUser`.